# Reach out to people who liked my app on facebook

Tags: facebook

I have about 30000 likes on a old facebook game. The likes are on the app itself. Not on any facebook page.
I had a embedded code generated from facebook a long time ago and putted that on the app page. How can I send an update to all people who liked this page to notify them that a new version of the game is ready to play? (I can't post anything because it is not a page.)
Kind regards

Comment: i am pretty sure that´s impossible, i am afraid

Comment: Not even a notification that something happened to the game?

Comment: no, because that would actually be weird...you cannot reach/notify people just because they liked some page or whatever. that would be spam, because they never agreed to getting notified.